# CSS and JS is not getting loaded in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, html, css, codeigniter

At first time home page is getting loaded and page is working fine, but on multiple hit to the same page, CSS and JS and images is not getting loaded in CodeIgniter.

All the images are present in the correct location, still it is showing me 404 error.

Error:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter-3.1.5/assets/images/resume.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Image path: source files -> assets -> images -> resume.jpg

CodeIgniter version : 3.1.5

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: this looks like a webserver problem other than a Codeigniter problem - which webserver r u using ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the base url in config/config.php as is required now days in codeigniter versions 3 >

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter-3.1.5/';
```

Make sure also assets out side of the application folder

```
application
assets -- folder permission 0777
system
index.php
```

You may need a htaccess also to remove the index.php

https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: the steps which you told I implemented in my setup, but still I am facing same issue.. no changes in the response.. plz help me further.. Thanks

Comment: Have you named your files and classes correct explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming Where only the first letter is upper case only.

Comment: In your Question please add where you load the links.

Comment: At first time css load in a correct manner.. after refreshing twice thrice, js and css stop its loading..

Comment: SO have you viewed the actual generated HTML on each refresh to see what your links etc looks like. Somethings changed and you should be able to see.